# Vqmod only make change if search doesn't exists

Tags: php, opencart

Is is possible in vQmod to checks if a method exists in a class. Only if it doesn't exist will it make the change.

E.g at the moment I have a simple vqmod which is causing problems with another extension that is also making the same change and causing the duplicate method error.

```
<file name="catalog/model/tool/image.php">
    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            class ModelToolImage extends Model {
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
            public function get($filename) {
                if (!file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $filename) || !is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $filename)) {
                    return;
                } 

                if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
                    return HTTPS_IMAGE . $filename;
                } else {
                    return HTTP_IMAGE . $filename;
                }   
            }
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Also is there any way to give priority to one vqmod over another. I need 2 vqmod files to already the code of the vqmod before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to add only if the method doesn't exist no. The trick is to "hijack" the original, or rename it. As for priority, they get parsed a to z so if you want it applied first, name it something that comes before the other alphabetically, or just prepend aaa to the name

Comment: Is there no easy way to add this feature into vqmod class? I don't like the idea of relying on the name of the other extension to always come before mine. This would cause far too many issues with people re-naming the file etc.

Comment: I guess this could also be used to solve the issue with: Note the affiliate library file may not exist on older systems.

Comment: Well unfortunately checking order of precedence would only slow the processing down, so at present there's no plans to add in something like that in vQmod, especially when you can just use naming. If something is also using zzz for its names, then chances are that want's to execute last - at which point even order of precedence wouldn't be of use if they're both fighting for it

Comment: Ok I understand why now, hadn't thought it would affect the performance.

Comment: Yeah, any form of sorting is going to affect performance, though depends on the number of items and complexity of the sorting algorithm as to just how much difference

Comment: It would be cool if in a future version of vqmod you had a condition in the search for if it doesn't exist. Something like this inside the operator: <search /><add /><where><operator>!=</operator><search>foo</search></where>